# How to set unpackwars=true in embedded tomcat server in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an application that uses Spring to create an executable `war` file.  The startup is pretty slow (3-6 minutes).  I have read other posts that this appears to be a setting with Apache Tomcat 8 where if `unpackWars=false` then performance is slow (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57251, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5200). But changing the `unpackWars=true` can help speed that up.  However, these posts are referring to a `server.xml` file which I don't have access to since this project is using an embedded tomcat server.

I first tried looking to see if there was some setting I can set in the `application.properties` file, but I don't seen anything off of `server` or `server.tomcat` that I might be able to use.

I have a `TomcatConfig` class that is consumed during startup and I am wondering if there is a way to set this `unpackWars` property to true to help speed up the start time.  I noticed what was happening in this class is similar to a post found here: (https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-context-path/)

```
@Slf4j
public class TomcatConfig {

@Value("${httpPort}")
private int port;

@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory(){
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(port);
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer() throws URISyntaxException, UnknownHostException {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if(container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory){
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                configureTomcat(containerFactory);
            }
        }
    };
}

private void configureTomcat(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory cf) {
    // configure unpackWars here somehow?
}
}
```

Comment: There is no native way to set it up from application.properties, as it is controlled by servlet container itself, not by Spring.

Comment: @fg78nc Is there any way you are aware of to modify the servlet container?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean exactly by modifying container?

Comment: I apologize, in your comment you said "...it is controlled by servlet container".  I was wondering if you had more insight into what that "servlet container" is or how it might be accessed.

Comment: Tomcat itself is servlet container.